# Passing String from Java file to jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json, string

I am not sure if this is possible, but can you pass the value of a string from Java file (Struts action) to jQuery (which is in custom.js, not in JSP)? The action file generates a JSON data, and I want the data to be passed to the jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is something like this:

```
<script>
     var msg= <%=msg%>;
</script>

<script src="files/js.js"></script>
```

You can do:

```
var msg= '<%= msg %>';
```

Then you can assign your `msg` variable to `JQuery` as you prefer, e.g.:

```
$(msg);
```

Note that you could need to use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` function beforehand to sanitize your string.

### Separate JS file

If you want to pass this string to a JS separate file, you can do it in an elegant and efficient way.

In your file.js:

```
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){
    var _args = {}; // private

    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
            // some other initialising
        },
        helloWorld : function() {
            alert('Hello World! -' + _args[0]);
        }
    };
}());
```

In your JSP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   MYLIBRARY.init(["msg", 1, "othervalue..."]);
   MYLIBRARY.helloWorld();
</script>
```

Comment: How about I want to pass the string to a JS file, not in JSP?

Comment: And my String is in a Java file, not in JSP.

Comment: Updated the answer to feed an external JS file

Comment: For the second comment, you can simply pass the string from your Java file to your JSP file as usual...

Comment: Don't forget to escape the single-quotes in the JSP when injecting the JavaScript string literal.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with "data to be passed to the jquery"?
the key words you should focus on are: client and server. 
server produces the datas and server consumes it.
how? you build a web-api rest method with your preferred framework/library (struts in your case) and then via $.ajax method consume it.

Comment: I have an Action class that generates data in JSON format. I want the program to pass that data in JSON format from my Java file to  jQuery.